# How to get JWT Token from Azure multi-tenant application?

Tags: azure, authentication, jwt, authorization, single-sign-on

I created a multi-tenant app on Azure Portal and sending request to get token with application's client Id. I am using the following URL to get token on Microsoft Azure AD

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

Sending a get request with parameters client_id={clientId}&response_type=token&scope=user.read+openid+profile+offline_access

However it is returning an access_token on given call-back url

> http://localhost:8082/my-callback-url#access_token=EwCIA8l6BAAU6k7%2bXVQzkGyMv7VHB/h4cHbJYRAAATb8xtkaxI5xsVkWM6etOevj7ADopBYP1/hj%2bUz%2bf1ZXH4lpykHkES1XBRBDNRDWwdqAA%2brO2tFlMygiuusVx1EJKvqeV0rPPaNDNX9azpWGzS45BN6WmXKcxzX623enNYJOdo%2bYyTtaMipFapvABOsjHve1nVwfq9zqpmcldnIhXBeGefdQsgqmBNjeAyAbWzifLNtdz6Ybxnbt8nMY5adb82Z8tsfddfDdjrqk%2bu%2b85%2bxKXO9Xop3wdRvrVC9FM46RniA6H3NUKjOMTJAsX4IQLjGjXM4eq9o95lmSzF3zgFOXI1rYwkDRVsFsLOgP8tx0occDcuVPQgMalXR6JREDZgAACIJRWLYJGUcWWAKPx26NmroNGG1xEkPB1kLeGk0Hf8324YZs2InsGvQBFUMU4XzGGNdj0s5rLYKK2ictDstHV1daM241F1M5FiaX1qCgdRXneR9uPzUsSIBOzPJtT1dD4k%2bDxp6Nr4hEnDPlymp5X0SR4v5vUA3aRhnsvmEzBVQDKR7cFvT7NSqVHSr/tTv/epdx81qgJcd6S6xF8oaMc7mn76jgU4YBn8jXYnTfGhUvhNZ8RJyyl71AqZrGr7JS2kStselZUgjavLqc9DdQD9cwPSWu1ketKmGgCjt6lVB3nlaw8Wxq%2by2/YhPznTRFD2wj/vzDOdTzCcZ9mJV%2bKMGcXYQqBiGE0MF8%2bWA1EKSXniT5UiegTfJkvnsgtx6G6sdV0rzFM7Xa9d/dHNDfyV5oGedZtJXE1WCUrEIUZZm/HNhhQyh0WSG0gWm3vOY7NAs13vey9lcIQ6Fllu6W/Ty3HE4llFp/9a3lNcujmlxsCASFUOX6R54xPJMt1ipF5lh5uyZCPoUda46UsrCDnNRg0dhuoSVwJMDHzDbs4NXhX4nhTOze/9koz6p5Ao4DtJ20LqmcylZDoLxUhXIU5vvnBYpiHwanBt2E/rG%2bqVEQbRy/v9fhi0chY0XPzldIm/Lz2l0%2b0MpJ/4l53f9YTRLdEMD8X8Umi35ZvpK9arAqgdRkx4/oWG9m8sxOMY2eASetiAJaU8yjtETgHpBGJTXbDVDpNA1s5NGc9QC%2brcSnGDV0BKIDYxBISR8TiJQVUaPqbNU1Mj3kGyQFnfS0jS83VGVfFCZ4cHkhDq/awLh2JrR0Ag%3d%3d&token_type=bearer&expires_in=3600&scope=User.Read%20openid%20profile

How can I validate this access token? or how can I get a JWT token instead?

Comment: access token are jwt. you can just get the token from the querystring. Which programming language are you using ? there are a lot of framework to do the job for you.

Comment: The above token in my question post is not JWT, as I tried it on jwt.io. Can you help me how to validate it?

Answer (score 0):

Your scopes are `user.read+openid+profile+offline_access`.
That first one is a Microsoft Graph API scope.
It's actually short-hand for `https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read`.
So you will get an access token that is meant for Microsoft Graph API.

The other scopes you defined affect the id token (openid, profile) or get you a refresh token (offline_access).

This means you cannot and should not validate the token.
Only Microsoft Graph API should be validating this token, since the token is meant for it.

If you want an access token for your API, you need to use a scope defined in the API's app registration (Expose an API section).